# Does 'without knowing' mean 'as we don't know' in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does ***without knowing*** mean 'as we don't know' in the first sentence? Or, just 'not accompanied by' or 'in the absence of,' as dictionaries say?

> The known fact of contingencies, ***without knowing*** precisely what those
> contingencies will be, entails that disaster preparation is not the
> same thing as disaster rehearsal. No matter how many mock disasters
> are staged according to prior plans, the real disaster will never
> mirror any one of them. Disaster-preparation planning is more like
> training for a marathon than training for a high-jump competition or a
> sprinting event. Marathon runners do not practice by running the full
> course of twenty-six miles; rather, they get into shape by running
> shorter distances and building up their endurance with cross-training.
> If they have prepared successfully, then they are in optimal condition
> to run the marathon over its predetermined course and length, assuming
> a range of weather conditions, predicted or not. This is normal
> marathon preparation.

[Ethics for Disaster](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=JjBOYQHYVh0C&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=training%20for%20a%20high%20jump%20competition%20or%20a%20sprinting%20event.%20Marathon%20runners%20do%20not%20practice%20by%20running%20the%20full%20course%20of%20twenty%20six%20miles;&source=bl&ots=nz8-OBCwcc&sig=ACfU3U0B_VF0uUdJf9RsM6SWpCLVAx5Bfg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivzsfs2K32AhW5w4sBHUdSD20Q6AF6BAgqEAM#v=onepage&q=training%20for%20a%20high%20jump%20competition%20or%20a%20sprinting%20event.%20Marathon%20runners%20do%20not%20practice%20by%20running%20the%20full%20course%20of%20twenty%20six%20miles%3B&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

It means *in the absence of*, as you suggest. The sentence would be easier to understand if it began like this:

> Knowing that contingencies exist, but not knowing precisely what those contingencies will be, ...